# Bash shell programming echo without jumping to next line

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter process name"
read process
if pgrep "$process" > /dev/null
then
    echo 0 $(awk '/Rss/ {print "+", $2}' /proc/`pidof $process`/smaps) | bc;
    echo "Kb"
else
    echo "Process $process not running"
fi
```

The output of the code above is

```
41250 
Kb
```

and I need the "Kb" output in the same line as the number like this

```
41250  Kb
```

Comment: `echo -n "text"` - will do ?

Comment: Have you tried printf using printf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `echo -n` to output data without a trailing newline but, for this particular case, `awk` is perfectly capable of doing arithmetic and formatting on its own, without involving `bc` or unnecessary sub-processes:

```
awk '/Rss/ {sum += $2} END {print sum" Kb"}' /proc/`pidof $process`/smaps
```

You can see that in the following transcript which adds up the two `Rss` figures `75` and `11` to get `86`:

```
pax> printf Rss 75\nCss 22\nRss 11\n' | awk '/Rss/ {sum += $2} END {print sum" Kb"}'
86 Kb
```

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-n` Flag.

Example:

```
echo -n 'I do not want a new line,'
echo ' because there is something else here.'
```

Use `$ man echo` to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

The newline after `41250` was actually from `bc`, not echo.

Capturing output of `bc` in a variable removes trailing newlines ([ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)).

```
#!/bin/bash
kbCount=$( echo "1+2" | bc)
echo $kbCount "Kb"
```

Now you should be able to fix it :)

Comment: Thanks, this one also worked